# How do I print lines from a file in python after and before a match?

Tags: python, loops, readfile

I would like to print some specific lines from a file, only those lines that come after a certain word appears on a line ('Ingredients:') and before another word appears ('Instructions:').
The file is a list of recipes and I want to be able to print out only the ingredients.

example of the text:

```
RECIPE : CACIO E PEPE #PASTA
Ingredients:
spaghetti: 200-g
butter: 25-gr
black pepper: as needed
pecorino: 50-gr
Instructions:
```

I tried this way and many others but nothing seems to work:

```
def find_line_after(target):
    with open('recipes.txt', 'r') as f:
        line = f.readline().strip()
        while line:
            if line == target:
                line = f.readline().strip()
                return f.readline()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def get_all_ingredients():
    flag = False
    with open('recipes.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if 'Instructions' in line:
                flag = False

            if flag:
                print(line.rstrip())

            if 'Ingredients' in line:
                flag = True


get_all_ingredients()
```

Tested input:

```
RECIPE : CACIO E PEPE #PASTA
Ingredients:
spaghetti: 200-g
butter: 25-gr
black pepper: as needed
pecorino: 50-gr
Instructions:
asd
RECIPE : CACIO E PEPE #PASTA
Ingredients:
salt: 200-g
chicken: 25-gr
Instructions:
qwe
qwe
RECIPE : CACIO E PEPE #PASTA
Ingredients:
carrot: 200-g
rabbit: 25-gr
Instructions:
qwe
qwe
```

Output got:

```
spaghetti: 200-g
butter: 25-gr
black pepper: as needed
pecorino: 50-gr
salt: 200-g
chicken: 25-gr
carrot: 200-g
rabbit: 25-gr
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
start, stop = 0, 0
with open('recipes.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for n in range(len(lines)):
    if 'Ingredients' in lines[n]:
        start = n + 1
    elif 'Instructions' in lines[n]:
        stop = n
ingredients = list(filter(('\n').__ne__, lines[start:stop]))
for i in ingredients:
    print(i, end='')
```

Basically looks for the start and stop indexes, fetches the lines from that range and removes the empty lines (and extra new-line chars).

Output:

```
spaghetti: 200-g
butter: 25-gr
black pepper: as needed
pecorino: 50-gr
```

Comment: your `for` loop is not correctly indented. In general all the code should be part of `with` block

Comment: It is properly indented and it works. Note that I'm iterating over all the lines read, this means **outside** the `with` statement.

Comment: your iteration should not occur if reading file failed for any reason. so it is not correctly indented. The fact it works **now** means nothing really.

Comment: If an error occurs in file reading, an exception is thrown and the code stops there. It has **nothing** to do with the indentations! What you propose is Ok when reading line by line.

Comment: Anyway, this is just meant to be a guide, this web is not a SW service, the person asking shall take further care/customization of the provided code, don't you think?

Comment: I ran the code and the last output (`pecorino: 50-gr`) is not got, maybe the line `stop = n - 1` must be `stop = n`

Comment: @NahuelBrandán you are right, because you ran the edited version of the question, the first version worked this way so it will depend a lot on the original text. I will edit it anyway, thanks for the observation!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! One thing I should've mentioned, the file contains various recipes and I need to extract this portion as many times as it occurs. With the code you kindly wrote for me, it seems it is printing out the very last time that this portion occurs. Thank you again, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

My approach involves setting a variable `is_ingredient` to True or False, depending on the line and print if it is True.

```py
is_ingredient = False
with open("recipes.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as stream:
    for line in stream:
        if line.startswith("Ingredients:"):
            is_ingredient = True
        elif line.startswith("Instructions:"):
            is_ingredient = False
            print("---")
        elif is_ingredient:
            print(line, end="")
```

The only addition I did was to print the `---` as a separator between recipes.